# itext7 - adding content from existing PDF to a new one

Tags: java, itext7

I'm trying to add some content to my PDF document to the first page of the document. What would be appropriate way of doing this?

At the moment my code works, but it adds(inserts) a new page before the first page of my document. What could be used here insted of the

```
    PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(1, PageSize.A4);
```

so the content from the document I'm reading is added to the existing first page as content and not as a new page

```
  public static void addContentToFirstPage(String inputFilePath,String filePath) throws IOException, DocumentException {

      File inFile = new File(inputFilePath);
      File outFile = new File(inputFilePath + "_numbering.pdf");

      PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inFile), new PdfWriter(outFile));
      PdfDocument origPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath));

      PdfPage origPage = origPdf.getPage(1);
      Rectangle orig = origPage.getPageSize();

      PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(1, PageSize.A4);

      PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
      AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(
                page.getPageSize().getWidth() / orig.getWidth(),
                page.getPageSize().getHeight() / orig.getHeight());

      canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
      PdfFormXObject pageCopy = origPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdf); 

      canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0);

      pdf.close();
      origPdf.close();

        // delete old file,rename new to old file
        inFile.delete();
        outFile.renameTo(new File(inputFilePath));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stamp your template page `origPage` onto the current first page of `pdf` instead of a new one, simply replace

```
PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage(1, PageSize.A4);
```

by

```
PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(1);
```

Now `page` references the already existing first page instead of a new one, and your further manipulations add the template page thereupon.

Comment: That's it. Thank you for your help :)